# php search/replace empty records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, replace

Trying to do a search and replace using php/mysql. I do this in specified table headers/columns. it works fine when my search term has a value. However i want to search for an empty field in a specified column and replace with a value. it fails to do a search and replace when my search term is an empty string. Any help?

```
$SearchAndReplace_header = isset($_POST['SearchAndReplace_header']) ? $_POST['SearchAndReplace_header'] : "";

$SearchAndReplace_search_term = isset($_POST['SearchAndReplace_search_term']) ? $_POST['SearchAndReplace_search_term'] : "";

$SearchAndReplace_replace_with = isset($_POST['SearchAndReplace_replace_with']) ? $_POST['SearchAndReplace_replace_with'] : "";

//foreach($fields as $key => $val) {
 //   if($SearchAndReplace_header == "all" || ($SearchAndReplace_header == $val)) {
        // replace column value with parameter value
        $sql = "UPDATE ".$table_name." SET ".$val." = REPLACE(".$val.",'".$SearchAndReplace_search_term."','".$SearchAndReplace_replace_with."')";                                              
        $db->query($sql);
   // }
  // }
```

Comment: Can you explain what is empty record? A record that does not exist ? or records matched certain `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Add an exception for `null` values. I think that `REPLACE()` can't find anything to replace when it encounters it.

Comment: @ajreal: empty records that has empty/null values

Comment: @karto - `NULL <> ''` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: @ajreal: i get it. but can u make an example to my codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do a replace on an empty field, you'll have to set the field directly.

```
UPDATE table 
SET column = 'value' 
WHERE column = '' or column is null
```

If you want to cover both cases in a single query, you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE table 
SET column = CASE 
                 WHEN column IS NULL OR COLUMN = '' 
                     THEN 'replace' 
                 ELSE
                      REPLACE(column, 'find', 'replace')
             END CASE
```

Comment: couldn't you just have just a normal if, as you only have 2 cases? SET column = IF(column IS NULL OR column = '', 'replace', REPLACE(column, 'find', 'replace'))

Comment: @Puggan Se: Pls try it on my code and let me see the clear picture